# Syntax for if-then-else in Racket

Tags: syntax, scheme, racket

I have a problem with Racket.

(I'm using the tutorial at http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/conditionals.html)

I tried to write a function that does this: If `x` is smaller than 4, then it should be incremented by 1, else it should be multiplied by 2.

```
(define (number x)
  (if (< x 4) 'x+1 'x*2))
```

So I compiled it on DrRacket, but it does nothing. The `(if (< x 5) 'x+1 'x*2))` -Part is marked black! I think the Problem is the `'` thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Lisps, the `'` is a shorthand for the `quote` operator, which prevents an S-Expression or symbol from being evaluated. While `x` would normally be a variable, quoting it turns it into a kind of lightweight string. Quotes are not part of the `if` syntax. It makes no sense to use quoting in your case.

Furthermore, Lisps do not use infix operators. Addition is just an ordinary function and everything, including addition, is written as an S-Expression. So instead of `x + 1` we would write `(+ x 1)`.

So our function would then look like:

```
(define (number x)
  (if (< x 4)
      (+ x 1)
      (* x 2)))
```